# Uplooad Video facebook-ios-sdk : uploaded but not shown on my FB Wall and in My Video

Tags: cocoa-touch, facebook, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have upload the video on facebook using following code
Help From : https://github.com/zoul/facebook-ios-sdk/
Full Discussion on Stackoverflow : [Facebook iOS Upload Video "Unable to retrieve session key from the access token."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552556/)

**Code**

```
FBVideoUpload *upload = [[FBVideoUpload alloc] init];
upload.accessToken = facebookObj.accessToken;
upload.apiKey = fbAppKey;
upload.appSecret = fbAppSecret;
NSString *filePath = @"/Users/pratgupta/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0010.M4V";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               @"test", @"title",
                                               @"upload testing", @"description",
                                               nil];
[upload startUploadWithURL:fileURL params:params delegate:self];
```

**By This I am getting this response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<video_upload_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">
  <vid>10150166760687147</vid>
  <title>test</title>
  <description>upload testing</description>
  <link>http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150166760687147</link>
</video_upload_response>
```

as it successfully upload the video, But I am not able to see it on **my Wall** ... even not in **My Videos**

Please check out these image

There is next previous when I open the link return in FB response and when I goes to the next video then next/previous not showing
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH7Ba.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUxTm.png

There is no next previous when I goes to my old video
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdHRF.png

When I goes to **My Videos** then there is no new video
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ2Ub.png

When I edit the image then shows its privacy as EVERYONE , means no privacy issue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR9BX.png

**EDIT**
Even with Privacy ; EVERYONE this video direct link not open in others profile 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgEjJ.png

**Amit Battan**

Comment: I'm noticing this, too. It was a brittle setup to be sure...maybe fb finally stopped it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the video uploaded and showing in profile ok.. I think it was the issue on FB API end